# xUnit mocked async test method not raise expected exeption

Tags: async-await, moq, xunit

The method under test:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption option, CancellationToken cToken)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
    }

    // other logic

    return _client.SendAsync(request, option, cToken);
}
```

The test which not work correctly:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SendAsync_ThrowExceptionOnNullRequest()
{
    var mockRestClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
    mockRestClient.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(
        It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        It.IsAny<HttpCompletionOption>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)));

    var excp = await Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync<ArgumentNullException>(
        async () => await mockRestClient.Object.SendAsync(
            null,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
            new CancellationToken(false)));

    Assert.NotNull(excp);
}
```

And the test with correct behavior:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SendAsync_ThrowExceptionOnNullRequest()
{         
    var restClient = new RestClient();

    await Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync<ArgumentNullException>(async () => await restClient.SendAsync(
        null,
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
        new CancellationToken(false)));
}
```

So, if I didnt use mocking this method I get expected behavior.
But the test with mock(ed) method not raise exception in any way.

How I should mock async method for test correctly?

Thanks.
PS

xUnit 2.4.1

.Net Core 2.1

Comment: What is your system under test, could you share it? Is it `RestClient` or something else?

Comment: Custom RestClient - wrapper over standard HttpClient

Comment: you already have the answer but that was my thought as well...that you are mocking SUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your incorrect test is setting up a mock to return a successful response, and then calls that mock expecting it to throw. So the test fails because it set up the mock to return a successful response.

> How I should mock async method for test correctly?

Don't mock the code you're testing. If you do that, you only test the mocking framework, not your own code. Mock types that are *used* by the code you're testing. That way you'll test your own code.